# SQLからのデータ読み取り時のエラー

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

SQLのデータをDataframeとして読み込むときにエラーが発生するため、質問しております。
具体的には以下のコードを走らせると、最後のコードを実行したときに、"TypeError: must be real number, not str"というエラーが発生します。
公式ドキュメント等で確認しても解決に至らず、みなさまのお知恵をお借りできると幸いです。
ご不明点などありましたらその旨お知らせください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
# データベースから必要なデータを抽出する
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///fundamental_database.sqlite3')
Base = declarative_base()

#model class
class FundamentalData(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'FundamentalData'
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    company_name = Column(String(30))
    sec_code = Column(Integer)
    para_name = Column(String(30))
    Q_n = Column(String(30))
    Date = Column(Numeric)
    value = Column(Numeric)
    type = Column(String(30))

# データベースに接続するためのセッションを準備
Session = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(bind = engine)
ses = Session()

Company_Funda_Data = ses.query(FundamentalData).filter(FundamentalData.company_name == 'トヨタ')

df = pd.read_sql_query(Company_Funda_Data.statement, engine)
```

Comment: エラーメッセージは略さず記したほうがよいでしょう。少なくとも "TypeError"だけではなかったはず。たぶん sqlite3 DB内に, real number がほしい部分に文字列が含まれているのだと思われます (データの問題)

Comment: 手元の環境では`Date`カラムを`Text`型にした状態で実行した場合にご質問のエラーが発生しました。pythonクラスの`Date`を`String(30)`などに変更することでエラー回避できるでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます
ご指摘の通り、データ型を変更すると先のエラーは発生せず読み取りできました

Answer (score 0):

これは、数値型の列には、DataFrame に読み取られるときに文字列が含まれるためです。

このエラーを解決するには、列のデータ型をデータベースから取得した結果に正しく変換する必要があります。

次のコードを試してください。

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(float)
df['value'] = df['value'].astype(float)
```

これで問題は解決しますか?